# What does an element of $\Bbb{Q}\otimes_\Bbb{Z}A$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, exact-sequence

I have the functor $~~~\Bbb{Q}\otimes_\Bbb{Z}-~~~$ from $\Bbb{Z}$-modules to $\Bbb{Q}$-vectorspaces. If I consider a left exact sequence of $\Bbb{Z}$-modules $$0\rightarrow A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B\rightarrow C$$and then apply the functor I get $$0\rightarrow \Bbb{Q}\otimes_\Bbb{Z}A\stackrel{id_\Bbb{Q}\otimes f}{\rightarrow} \Bbb{Q}\otimes_\Bbb{Z}B\rightarrow \Bbb{Q}\otimes_\Bbb{Z}C$$ First I only want to check that $\ker(id_\Bbb{Q}\otimes f)=im(0\rightarrow \Bbb{Q}\otimes_\Bbb{Z}A)$. So more precisly I want to check that $\ker(id_\Bbb{Q}\otimes f)=0$. But my problem is that I don't see how an element looks like in $\Bbb{Q}\otimes_\Bbb{Z}A$. I mean I know that in $u\otimes v\in U\otimes V$ where $(u,v)\in U\times V$. But is it here the same so does an element looks like $q\otimes a$ for $(q,a)\in \Bbb{Q}\times A$? Because in the lecture our prof somehow wrote something like $\sum_i q_i\otimes a_i$. Why do we need a sum? Is this more useful to prove injectivity? And is my idea with $q\otimes a$ wrong or does it also works with this representation?

It would be nice if someone could explain this to me a bit in detail since I'm really confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not every element of $U\otimes V$ is of the form $u\otimes v$.  Instead a general element is a sum of elements of this form.  (If you don't understand why this is true then you should review the definition/construction of $U\otimes V$.)

Comment: @EricWofsey the problem is, that we have never really costructed $U\otimes V$. We have only that it satisfies the universal property of the tensorproduct. We don't have any more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @EricWofsey says in the comments is true, and yet in the special case of $\mathbb Q \otimes_{\mathbb Z} A$ we can rewrite a general element in the form $q \otimes a$ by "adding fractions".

Consider a general element $\sum_i q_i \otimes a_i$ where $q_i = \frac{n_i}{d_i}$ with $n_i,d_i \in \mathbb Z$ and $d_i > 0$. Let $d$ be the "least common denominator", that is, the least common multiple of the $d_i$'s. Let $p_i = d / d_i$ so $q_i = \frac{n_i p_i}{d}$. Then
$$\sum_i q_i \otimes a_i = \sum_i \frac{n_i p_i}{d} \otimes a_i = \sum_i \frac{1}{d} n_i p_i \otimes a_i = \frac{1}{d} \otimes \sum_i n_i p_i a_i
$$
and clearly $\sum_i n_i p_i a_i \in A$.

Comment: As I wrote above, the problem is that we have never seen a construction/definiton of the tensor product, I mean we only had $u\otimes v$ as elements and defined what the operation needs to satisfy. But as I understood it correctly always if I have $U\otimes V$ then an element is $\sum_{i\in I} u_i\otimes v_i\in U\otimes V$

Comment: Note, all that I have used in my answer is those properties that the operation needs to satisfy: each of the three equations in my derivation follows directly from one of those properties.

Comment: In fact, the first two equations are just rewriting $q_i$. The last equation then uses two of the properties of the tensor product over $\mathbb Z$, namely: $(x m) \otimes a = x \otimes (ma)$ for any integer $m$ (in this case $m=n_ip_i$; and then $\sum_i x \otimes b_i = x \otimes \sum_i b_i$.

Comment: Sure but does a general element always look like this $\sum_i q_i\otimes a_i$? S I mean also in a general tensor product $U\otimes V$ we have $\sum_i u_i\otimes v_i$

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. In $U \otimes V$ the general element has the form of a finite sum $\sum_i u_i \otimes v_i$ where $u_i \in U$ and $v_i \in V$. And in the case $U=\mathbb Q$ and $V=\mathbb Z$ we have exactly that form, with different variables $q_i$ instead of $u_i$, and $a_i$ instead of $v_i$.

Comment: Yes so that's what I wanted to know how a general element in a general tensor product $U\otimes V$ looks like